# Sideway figures on multiple pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, sidewaysfigure

I want to place two sub figures span on multiple pages in sideway figure mode

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
         \caption{\label{fig 4.10.a}figure a}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/characterization/j2/Figure 1.a_R1.pdf}
     \end{subfigure}   
     \hfill
\end{sidewaysfigure} 
\clearpage 
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[H] 
\ContinuedFloat
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
         \caption{Figure b}
         \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/characterization/j2/Figure 1.b_R1.pdf}
         \label{fig 4.10.b}
     \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure 10}
  \label{fig 4.10}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

But only first figure is getting displayed, second figure is missing in the PDF file.

Comment: `\begin{sidewaysfigure}` instead of  `\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]` and `\begin{sidewaysfigure}[H]` should result in the expected output.

Comment: Optional placement parameter`h` and `H` should not use in `sideways`

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement leandriis's comment with compilable code. Please do not accept as an answer.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
            \caption{\label{fig 4.10.a}figure a}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{subfigure}   
        \hfill
    \end{sidewaysfigure} 
    \newpage
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
        \ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
            \caption{Figure b}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \label{fig 4.10.b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Figure 10}
        \label{fig 4.10}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to replace a sequence of `sidewaysfigure`s with sequence of  `figure`s on landscape oriented pages?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is simpler and more reliable to use the `landscape` environment encapsulated in `\afterpage{ ...}` than two successive `sidewaysfigures`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\afterpage{
    \clearpage
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\caption{figure a}
\label{fig 4.10.a}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    %\newpage
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\caption{Figure b}
\label{fig 4.10.b}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
        \caption{Figure 10}
        \label{fig 4.10}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
    }
\lipsum[2-11]

\end{document}
```

[image]